# Displaying the Characters Represented with an Integer in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a report where it lists the race, ethnicity and county of a client. Right now, the report displays 1,2,3, etc. for the race that has been selected as opposed to Black, White, Other, etc. This is also the case for ethnicity and county. I'm wondering what is the proper way to display the letter description as opposed to the integer for the race, ethnicity, and county. I've included my query below, any assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

```
SELECT 
    person.idFamily AS Family_ID, 
    person.id AS Person_ID,
    (SELECT person.firstName+ ', ' + person.lastName) AS Name,
    person.Race AS Race, 
    person.Ethnicity AS Ethnicity, 
    family.capidCounty AS County, 
    person.birthDate AS BirthDate,
    DATEDIFF(year,person.birthDate,getdate()) as Age
  FROM Family
  LEFT JOIN person ON family.Id = person.idFamily
```

Comment: how could anyone know where is the ethnicity info stored in your DB, without sharing your DB structure??

Comment: You would join in the reference tables and use the appropriate name columns in them.

Comment: Do you have tables for race, ethnicity, and country? If you have them, post them. Otherwise, you'll need to use an explicit CASE to show texts instead of codes.

Comment: Create a masterdata table where you hold the information and join it to your resultset. MAybe you should show some sample data and expected results too. And if you dont have the text how do you then know that 1 equals Black?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I was able to find the correct tables and get the text as opposed to the code to display (I've included the modified query below). The only other issue I'm encountering is that if a client's race or ethnicity information was set to 'Not Assigned', this is a NULL and I'm having difficulty adding a CASE statement so that NULL information shows as 'Not Assigned'. Thank you again for the previous suggestions, any assistance with correctly implementing a CASE statement would be much appreciated, I tried adding it to my SELECT statement but received a syntax error.

Comment: SELECT person.idFamily AS Family_ID, person.id AS Person_ID,(SELECT person.firstName+ ', ' + person.lastName) AS Name, race.Description AS Race, ethnicity.value AS [Hispanic or Latino], person.birthDate AS BirthDate, DATEDIFF(year,person.birthDate,getdate()) as Age
FROM Family
LEFT JOIN person ON family.Id = person.idFamily
LEFT JOIN Ethnicity race ON race.Id = Person.Race
LEFT JOIN lookupYesNo ethnicity  on ethnicity.id = person.ethnicity
LEFT JOIN capRaceOther on capRaceOther.id = Person.raceother